# How to have an image in background of plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, background

I have a plot from a network of lines in 3D space and I have one image from the object as well. Now I want to put the image file in the background of my plot as a fixed background and then the network should be plotted on that background. By the way, since the Network is in 3D space I can rotate it easily and it is important for me rotate the network on the my combined plot as well.

this is my code that I have written but it shows my plot separately! if I put imshow inside the figure then image will be ploted on the top of my network and I can see only one point of my network. Here is the link of [Network](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=60812900386881588685) and the background image from [background](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=20856568002520937768)
Here is my code: the first line plot the image and the rest of the code plot my network of lines:

```
Img1 = imshow('STP1.png');
figure('name','Distance');
hold on;
labels = cellstr( num2str([1:SIFT_Length]') );  
text(SIFT_3D(:,1), SIFT_3D(:,2),SIFT_3D(:,3),labels,'FontWeight','bold','FontSize', 12,...
 'VerticalAlignment','bottom','HorizontalAlignment','right')
title('Distances Network with colorized lines based on Uncertainty','FontWeight','bold');
hold on
for k = 1:Num_Line_SIFTS
       plot3([SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,1),1),SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,2),1)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,1),2),SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,2),2)],...
       [SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,1),3),SIFT_3D(Line_among_2_Sifts(k,2),3)],...
       'o-','Color',[RGB_0_1(k,1) RGB_0_1(k,2) RGB_0_1(k,3)],'MarkerFaceColor',[RGB_0_1(k,1) RGB_0_1(k,2) RGB_0_1(k,3)],'MarkerEdgeColor',...
       'k', 'LineWidth',2)
 end
hold off;
```

Please help me how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `imshow` after the `hold on` command and before you plot anything else?

Comment: I tested your suggestion too. But it doesn't work! all points of network will be jammed in one point!! and As I told, only the network should be rotatable and the background should be fixed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your need, nevertheless ...

```
figure('name','Distance','unit','normalized');

a=axes('position',[0 0 1 1])
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% UPDATED CODE STARTS HERE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Disable zoom
h=zoom;
setAllowAxesZoom(h,a,false);
% Disable rotation
h = rotate3d;
setAllowAxesRotate(h,a,false) 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% UPDATED CODE ENDS HERE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
hold on
imshow('Jupiter_New_Horizons.jpg','parent',a)

t=0:.01:2*pi;
z=sin(t).*cos(t)
a1=axes('position',[0.3 0.3 .5 .5])

plot3(cos(t),sin(t),z,'r','linewidth',3)
grid on
set(gca,'color','none')
```

This script generates the following graph:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! I think you got it right and I misunderstood the question haha +1

Comment: Thank you @Benoit_11. Your answer came first, I should refresh the page while I'm answering. About the interpretation of the question ... well ... let see what user3185893 thinks :-)

Comment: @ il_raffa, this is exactly that I need but I think my network and my image is not in a same size since all points of my network are jammed in the top left corner my plot window! I have to zoom in many times to see my network and when I zoom in then the background is zoomed as well. the background should not be zoom able and rotatable !!! but here is zoom able and rotatable too ! can you tell me how can I fixed the background and only top layer rotatable and zoom able ?

Comment: The background image is linked to an axes, this is why when you zoom on the plot the background image is zoomed as well. To disable the zoom on a specific axes, you can use the function `setAllowAxesZoom`. You can find a compete example in the answer I've provided here: [Remove zoom from GUI axes in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072704/remove-zoom-from-gui-axes-in-matlab).

Comment: I've updated the script in order to disable both zoon and rotation on the axes containing the background image. Hope this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
clear
clc
close all


%// Read image
Im=flipud(imread('STP1_low.png'));

%// Dummy surface to plot.
Z = peaks(25);

%// Prepare image position
shift = 20;
xIm=zeros(size(Z))-shift;

hold on
surface(xIm,Im,'FaceColor','texturemap','EdgeColor','none','CDataMapping','direct')
surface(Z,'FaceAlpha',0.8,'LineStyle','none','FaceColor','interp');
axis on
view(-35,45)

box on
rotate3d on
```

Output:

[image]

You can rotate it and the image stays as the background.

Comment: When I try to load image by your given function Im=flipud(imread('peppers.png'));  Matlab gives me this error : X must be a 2-D matrix.! I can't even load the image file. can you please have a look at background image that I put its link in my question and see that can you load it by your code?

Comment: yep that works fine; I just edited the answer. Are you sure the error is generated by the call to `imread`?

Comment: mhh that's weird. What if you omit `flipud`?